# Ionic 5 / Angular 9 serve does not show typescript errors

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, interface

I have two interfaces in my Ionic 5 / Angular 9 project

```
export interface NavItem {
    routerLink: string,
    icon: string,
    title: string
}

export interface NavItems {
    items: NavItem[]
}
```

And then I'm using them in a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavItem, NavItems } from '../interfaces/navigation';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigationService {
  private mainNavigation : NavItems = {
      items: "A"
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

I would now expect, that ionic serve shows me an error and tells me, that it is not possible to compile this, because I totally ignore the specification of the interface.

But ionic serve just compiles as it was nothing.

Do I misunderstand a concept here? Why does this work?

Here is the Link to my typescript config files:
[Typpescript config](https://pastebin.com/FpDexhDY)

Comment: Can you share the tsconfig.json file of your app?

Comment: @Shravan: Added a link

Comment: Show an screenshot of error, please!

Comment: @1antares1: There is no error, that`s the problem

Comment: Ok, now I compile it with Cordova and I get all the typescript errors. Which setting do I have to change to get them with the ionic test server?